# AdMob - Error inflating Class com.google.gms.AdView

Tags: java, android, xml, admob

I cannot add adverts to my android app, I have spent the last 6 hours trying to get it to work and researching fixes, but nothing seems to work! So frustrating.

here is the code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    init();
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearSplash);

    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("a14ff402be4457c");

    layout.addView(adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .build();

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

But I get the error:

```
Unable to start activity - android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class com.google.gms.ads.AdView
```

Is there a fix? I am using the `google play services` jar file, not the normal admob 6.4.1 one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong `AdView` in your layout file.

You have to use `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView` in your layout as `google play services` has that package and not the one that you use currently(probably `com.google.gms.ads.AdView`)